# any C/C++ open-source RTMP streaming server?

Tags: c++, c, video-streaming, rtmp, live-streaming

do you know any C/C++ open-source RTMP streaming server?

Comment: I once built my own using ffmpeg. Not that hard. Unfortunately I've lost the code.

Comment: @Emil: how ffmpeg helps here? handles source file container format or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

http://www.rtmpd.com/

Excellent project.

Comment: That website appears to no longer exist.

Answer (score 2):

Nginx with RTMP Module:

https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module

You include it when you build Nginx, and now you have a fast web server with RTMP support.